# Iterating hash map and getting values to string array

Tags: android, hashmap

Can anyone help me to iterate on a hash map, and store value to string array? 
I have a hash map with two keys and corresponding values under each keys. Since the value set is large, I want to iterate values from hash map for each key and store in to a string array. Please help.

Comment: Do you want all values in the same String array? No matter what key the value is from? Also what data type is the value? Is it an array? A list?

Comment: @Dom I want all values under the same key in to an array. I have stored a key and several values under the key in hashmap.both the key and values are string

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
List<String> valuesList =new ArrayList<>();

for(String key:mHash.keySet()){
   valuesList.add(mHash.get(key));
}
```

to Strings Array :

```
String[] stockArr = new String[valuesList.size()];
stockArr = valuesList.toArray(stockArr);
```

Comment: I didn't understand this code. if my hash map have a key "countries" and lots of values under the key , how will i retrieve that values to a string array? could you please tell?

Answer (score 1):

make a new string array of the same size as your hashmap.
loop through your hashmap and assign each iteration to an element in your array.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[mHashMap.keySet().size()];
int i = 0;
for(String key: mHashMap.keySet()){
    stringArray[i] = mHashMap.get(key);
    i++;
}
```

the for loop that i have shown above, and as another also commented can be read as follows:

```
for(String key : mHashMap.keySet()){
 //do this
}

"for all keyStrings in myHashMap.keyStringSet(), do this"
eg. for each item in the hashmap, do whatever is in the brackets.
```

Your string array is completed.

Comment: Still I am not clear about how to iterate the values i want.i know the key.there are around 50 values under one single key. all i want is to get all the values under those keys in to seperate arrays.could you help?

Comment: A hashmap stores one value against one key, you cant have multiple values with the same key.